# Touchscreen works for finger BUT it stops working when putting the stylus pen

Tags: drivers, updates, touchscreen, wacom, stylus

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 on a Lenovo IdeaPad c340, i did drawing for a while and everything worked fine, but I didn't use my stylus since two days today eventually I had an update on my computer then I tried to draw something but I realized my stylus didn't work anymore, I restarted then the screen touch worked fine for my fingers but once i put the stylus en on my screen it stops working even for my fingers, it's the same history whenever i restart my computer everything works fine till i put the stylus :(
I'll appreciate it if you have any idea to do, I did a lot of research on internet and nothing worked...
and do you think it's due to the 20.4.2 released version? because i have 20.4.1 on a usb and when i enter in live mode it works fine...
Thank you!
here my (xinput)

```
    ⎡ Virtual core pointer                        id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                  id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ USB Optical Mouse                           id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ MSFT0001:02 04F3:304B Mouse                 id=11    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ MSFT0001:02 04F3:304B Touchpad              id=12    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Wacom HID 51CA Pen stylus                   id=13    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Wacom HID 51CA Finger touch                 id=14    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Wacom HID 51CA Pen eraser                   id=17    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                       id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard                 id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                                id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                   id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                                id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated Camera: Integrated C             id=10    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Ideapad extra buttons                       id=15    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard                id=16    [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Update: updating Kernel to 5.8.0-49-generic in Dell 7400 with ubuntu 20.04 solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be this bug https://github.com/linuxwacom/input-wacom/issues/230. It's been patched, but not yet in the ubuntu kernel.